# How do I use animated PNG in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-xe3, apng

How do I use animated PNG in Delphi?

Answer (score 4):

If you are still searching for a solution  then you can take a look
[here](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=down) where I've found this library that can solve your trouble.
With this complete library you can open APNG file then get number of frames etc...